# Specify date format while importing data in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to import data in CSV file use Oracle SQL Developer. One of the columns in CSV file is date which is in ISO-8601 format **`2012-08-22T00:06:52.0Z`** with fractional second as always 0. Corresponding column in table is of type **date**. Oracle SQL Developer has option to specify date format in import process so I specify the format as

```
YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS."0Z"
```

[image]
But import process fails saying date format is not recognized. Insert statements that Oracle SQL Developer is generating somehow is removing double quotes from the date format.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) VALUES (to_date('2009-02-18T00:06:52.0Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.0Z'),to_date('2012-08-30T00:06:52.0Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.0Z'));
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: 2 years later and I ran into a similar issue with the latest version of SQL developer. Still no answers to this question it seems. I got around it by opening my data file in TextPad and using a few regex expressions to get the data into a state that oracle supports. Not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Your format (YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS".0Z") of date and I was success. I have SQL Developer 23.1.0.097. May be try newer version of developer. Status error in second picture I ignored and succesfully went to next step.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Did you try escaping the characters in the date format specification? if that doesn't work you should open an SR about it.